# Cross-platform C/C++ RabbitMQ Library with minimal dependencies

Tags: c++, c, rabbitmq, amqp

I am looking for Cross-platform C/C++ RabbitMQ Library with minimal dependencies.

I checked all libraries mentioned on RabbitMQ site but none of them seems acceptable for me.

I am looking for something which will work outside of the box without need for tons of libraries or specific OS. One header file and one source file will be just fine.

What do you do use for working with AMQP?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LibRabbitmq is the option for C/C++ implementation of RabbitMQ.

Source code and good examples are present at https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c.

Creating a simple consumer and publisher using libRabbitmq is quite easy free. You would require one library and few header files.

Comment: Years later this is still relevant. I've inherited some legacy code and this still builds with vc2005 with minimal tweaking. It just breaks when C files try to declare and define on the same line but those few and far between.